# JBoss EAP 6.4 -> 7.1 Using hibernate 4 instead of default hibernate 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

We are trying to **upgrade** and migrate from hibernate **6.4** to **7.1**.

We have run the migration tools for this which have touched our standalone.xml and everything looks kind of ok now.

However, our project uses hibernate 4 (default in 6.4) but 7.1 uses hibernate 5 and we are running into hibernate errors on startup.

What is the best and easiest way to **use** **hibernate 4** instead of **hibernate 5** in 7.1 ?

We are running a **maven** project and as far as I can see there are no signs of any **hibernate declarations** anywhere in the pom files.

However, there are references to jboss-as-web and jboss-as-maven-plugins but unsure what they actually do. Maybe another version could resolve this?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-web</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>7.4.Final</version>
   </plugin>
```

I am thinking defining **hibernate** **dependency** in pom might resolve this, and force jboss eap to use hibernate, but unsure would be to define in standalone to use hibernate 4. Roundrobin time is kind of big.

Any thoughts or ideas on if it is possible to use **hibernate 4 instead of hibernate 5**?

Comment: I would recommend not to use another hibernate version but the provided one, except Redhat is providing a documentation how to do so. Instead, I would go after the mentioned hibernate errors on startup. Since you are using JBoss EAP, you should be able to open a ticket with Redhat for this (regarding the hibernat errors and/or switching the hibernate version).

Comment: @Frito there is a problem with the license and waiting for that to submit a ticket. However, forcing us to use hibernate 5 requires a lot of code updates. 4 and 5 are not 100% compatible.

Comment: I found this one: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JPA+Reference+Guide

but it's not fully clear. Some files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I may quote from the original JBoss documentation. I guess not ;-)

Please have a look at the [JBoss EAP 7.1 Migration Guide - Chapter 5.7.2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/migration_guide/#migration_hibernate_orm_4_0_4_3).